Is there a way to automatically switch between two windows of the same app in Windows 10
I have two windows of the same program that i am constantly switching over manually, (each window needs the whole screen). Is there a way to automate the process of switching between them for let's say 30 seconds?
Basically one in the background and one in the foreground, I want each window to appear for 30 seconds for example.
I have tried using some GPT scripts with Autohotkey but no luck!

Do you just want Alt+Tab? In AutoHotKey, you can move a window to the front with WinActivate. If they have the exact same title/text, then you might want to use WinActivateBottom to specifically bring the back one to the front when more than one window matches
